# Split variable into multiple variables in python

Tags: python, variables, split

In python, I have a variable with 2 lines of stuff which I want to split into 2 different variables. I also want it to do it for any number of lines, for example I can change the number of lines and it automatically splits it for how many lines there are. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Assuming you're referring to a string: `string.split('\n')`. However, if you sometimes don't know how many lines there are, you'd have to create variable names dynamically, which is almost always a bad idea. Instead, use the list that `.split()` produces directly.

Comment: That wont work for what I want to do later. For each line, I want to get the last 4 characters to be used for one thing and the rest for another. So I need each line as a different variable. Unless there is another way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sometimes unsure about how many lines there are, you'd be forced to dynamically create variable names. **Don't do this**. This is almost always the wrong approach to take, and a better way exists.

Instead, use the list that `.split()` produces directly, and process the data inside of *that*.

If you need to further split each line in your string into two parts, you can use nested lists. Here is a simple example of the method I think you should use instead:

```
# your input string
string = "first line\nsecond line\nthird line\nfourth line"

# use a list to store your data, and proccses it instead.
data = []

for line in string.split('\n'):
    # split each line into two parts.
    first_part, second_part = line[:-4], line[-4:]
    data.append([first_part, second_part])

# data:
#
# [['first ', 'line'], 
# ['second ', 'line'], 
# ['third ', 'line'], 
# ['fourth ', 'line']]  
print(data)
```

You can access each part of `data` using a certain index. For example, if you wanted to process the first line of `string`, you could use `data[0]` which yields `['first ', 'line']`.

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @IanStegner I'm not sure what your saying. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I get that error at this line: for line in string.split('\n'): when I put my data in.

Comment: @IanStegner Is your data a list or a string? I assumed your data was a string.

Comment: ['@HISzISzAzTESTzMESSAGEb;9763\n', '.88OQYN8VSN!31PWS7NO8N2332p;7502\n', '7XKF5U1FXKGJ5FZUFGZZGIQfF,*0lF[NXYh;4400']

Thats my data

Comment: I fixed it. It's now a string

Comment: Nice to hear Ian, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

something like below

```
>>> a="""this is a
multiline
string"""
>>> for eachline in a.split('\n'): print(eachline)

this is a
multiline
string
```

Comment: How do I get each line into a different variable. For example, a1 = this is a
b1 = multiline
c1 = string

Answer (score 0):

when you split the string it gets converted into a list.

```
>>> split_list=a.split('\n')
>>> split_list
['this is a', 'multiline', 'string']
```

then you can access via

```
>>> var1=split_list[0]
>>> var1
'this is a'
```

and so on...
else you can run a for loop to get each item of the list

```
for eachline in a.split('\n'): print(eachline)
```

Comment: Instead of creating a _new_ answer to the question, edit your exiting question and delete this one.